# Magento 2: How to change Payment Action Method on the fly in Paypal Express

Tags: php, payment-gateway, magento2, paypal

I have already created Paypal/Developer/Sandbox Account. Already got API Credentials.

Downloaded PHP SDK http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/

Referring: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/

https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/expresscheckout/php?interactive=ON&env=sandbox

I have already done Sandbox One Transaction with **Authorize** Method using my PHP Script.

What i have to achieve. **I need to get Authorize Payments, Convert "Authorize" payments to "Capture/Sale" Method & Notify Customer & Admin As well.**

How to get Authorization Id?

By referring above document i need to use 3 Web Services

- Get details of an authorized payment
- Capture an authorized payment
- Get details of a captured payment

Already have Transaction ID of "Authorize" Payment.

Please provide the steps to follow & if any example already available then please share

**Need to integrate this functionality in Magento 2**

**[UPDATE]**

I have changed my API Sandbox Credentials in PHP SDK in `PayPal-PHP-SDK-master\sample\bootstrap.php` file.

From `sample/payments/AuthorizePayment.php` i will get Authorized Payment with ID: PAY-0TV39791XXX02404VK7XD32I & it works fine.

When i input my `Transaction Id` it gives

> {"name":"INVALID_RESOURCE_ID","message":"Requested resource ID was not
>   found.","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#INVALID_RESOURCE_ID","debug_id":"1f2b08ce88633"}

My Sandbox Transaction Id is `3AA32794KF48247AA`. So question is how to convert your Transaction Id in to Payment Id?

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/138579/magento-2-change-paypal-action-method-on-the-fly

Below is the reply from Paypal

> Transaction id can be generated after REST API execute payment,
>   Classic API [NVP/SOAP] DoEC API or normal button payment completion.
>   It will never work to reverse the search to find the Payment Id.

Comment: It's up to SO Moderators whether they wanna switch question from SO site to http://magento.stackexchange.com or Not? Becuase final result of this i want in Magento 2. Thanks

Comment: Hi SO Community, Please guide me to achieve functionality. Thanks

Comment: Hi, I've updated my answer, see below.

Answer (score 1):

If you have paymentId, you can get details of authorized payment in this way:

```
$payment = Payment::get( $paymentId, $apiContext );
```

For all propeties of payment class take a look this - [Payment.php](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/lib/PayPal/Api/Payment.php)

To change Sandbox/API Credentials edit the [bootstrap.php](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/sample/bootstrap.php) in your project.

**UPDATE**

You don't need to use AuthorizePayment.php. Istead, do the following:

1. Create payment and get the url for authorization (your website side).
2. Print the url for authorization (your website side).
3. Cutomer follow the authorization url and go to PayPal and authorize the payment (PayPal side).
4. PayPal returns customer to your website with the paymentId (PayPal side).
5. Grab the paymentId and execute the payment (your website side).

Comment: PaymentId = Transaction ID? I have Transaction Id. How to get PaymentId on basis of TransactionId?

Comment: When the payment approved on PayPal side it returns to your website with the paymentId as a get-parameter, added to your returning url. Can you clarify how do you get the TransactionId?

Comment: Although i have transaction id stored in My Database from Paypal. Still i have to create whole thing again?

Comment: provide more information. Do you have transaction id from previous payment?

Comment: Yes if you check in question i already mentioned & reply from Paypal as well

Comment: and you need to repeat the payment? In your question, what to you mean under 'authorized' payment? maybe you mean executed?

Comment: Paypal Methods:
[1] Authorize: Approves the purchase, but puts a hold on the funds. The
amount is not withdrawn until it is “captured” by the merchant.
[2] Sale: The amount of the purchase is authorized and immediately
withdrawn from the customer’s account.

Comment: Should it be a single payment or regular?

Comment: If you need to repeat your previous payment, you need to use explore different part of api - [billing](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/tree/master/sample/billing). If single - described above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125311/discussion-between-ankit-shah-and-stweb).

Comment: About your last question on chat: I think you need to use [billing](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/tree/master/sample/billing)

Comment: HI @stweb u have working example for this? It's not working